# Yii Cgridview Dynamic Columns

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I am looking at customising the yii cgridview. I want to be able to allow users to select which columns they wish to see. Currently I am selecting the exact columns which will be displayed.

I have had a look for information on this but do not seem to be getting very far, maybe I am not looking for the correct terms or their is a specific term for this. Ideally users can click a button and tick the boxes which will be seen. I have seen this implemented on x2crm

http://demo.x2engine.com/index.php/accounts/index

I also like the ability to move the columns around ie resort the order of the columns and the ability to resize the columns when more are added. I realise someone isn't going to come along and do this for me, but certainly if someone could provide me any information or similar requests, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long gruelling search I have found something that may in fact be the solution to both of my requests. An extension for Yii exists that allow for you to chooser the columns you wish to display with a simple tick box selection, as well as allowing for reordering of columns.

http://ecolumns.demopage.ru/index.php

The link above takes you to the demo page for the extension and the link below is the link to the extension download page.

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/ecolumns/

This is by far the easiest way to implement this functionality on your web app.

Answer (score 1):

Start by reading the docs for CGridView,

The constructor for it takes in an array specifying which columns to display (and whether to allow sort on them, etc) so allowing users to select which columns they want to see is almost trivial:

Display a form with checkboxes, the values of which are the names of the columns. When the user submits the form, loop over the checkboxes and add each of the present fields to the array that is passed to CGridView.

It is a little more complicated if you want to have specific settings for the column (i.e. a specific column header, or formatting) however not too much - in that case you just define an array holding the settings for it, and add that array to the total array you submit to CGridView.

Allowing drag and drop of the columns is a far more challenging enterprise, and may not actually be possible without a custom implementation - this is because CGridView is inherently just a table i.e. you could drag and drop rows easily (as they are whole items), but dragging a dropping a row is in reality dragging and dropping a lot of separate cells. However, there are jQuery examples that could get you started - and it wouldnt be a huge issue to implement a CGridView that uses divs instead of a table, and uses cells inside columns, rather than cells inside rows.

I hope that helps a little.